# Change Source Directory in Clickhouse

Tags: clickhouse

I'm trying to change `/var/lib/clickhouse` to something like `/mnt/sdc/clickhouse` so that i could have clickhouse in another hard disk. I've tried this steps:

‍‍1. Stop Clickhouse 
2. Move directory `/var/lib/clickhouse` to `/mnt/sdc/clickhouse`
3. Replace all `/var/lib/`s to `/mnt/sdc/` in file `/etc/clickhouse-server/config.xml`
4. Start Clickhouse

But the problem is `/var/lib/clickhouse` contains hard links so when i `mv` the directory, this hard links become corrupted.

Is this OK or not?
How should i change the clickhouse directory?

Comment: tar able to preserve hardlinks

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/44247/how-to-copy-directories-with-preserving-hardlinks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To copy files while preserving hard links, you can use `rsync` with `--hard-links` (or `-H`) option. For your setup, you should be able to run the following:

```
rsync -a -H /var/lib/clickhouse/ /mnt/sdc/clickhouse
```

Note the trailing slash after the first directory to copy the directory contents rather than the directory itself.

Then, as you mentioned, update the `/var/lib/` paths to `/mnt/sdc/` in `/etc/clickhouse-server/config.xml`, and restart ClickHouse with `systemctl restart clickhouse-server`.

I was able to follow these steps to migrate ClickHouse data to a new disk mount using `rsync`, and ClickHouse restarted successfully using the new disk (ClickHouse v22.3 on Ubuntu 18.04).

Comment: I am very curious how you changed ownership of a folder from a mounted drive? is you file system `FAT2/3/4`? Because `NTFS`wouldn't allow you to do that (changing permission of a folder from mounted drive)